# Dynamic Programming - How to get the solution from the predecessor matrix

Tags: dynamic-programming

Whenever I'm coding a dynamic program , I usually struggle building the solution from the predecessor matrix . How should use the predecessor matrix to find the solution ?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a very general question. Do you have any particular problem in mind?

Answer (score 3):

That depends a lot on the question, really. But basically, since you have the values of the all your "sub-problems", and you know your formula for the problem (Meaning, how the current problem is solved using the optimized solutions for the smaller problem), you can just check which cells (That are possible optimized solutions) in the matrix satisfy this formula.

Then, you can know that this cell is part of the solution.

Continue this way from top to bottom - and you'll get your whole solution (And not just the value, which is I guess was your problem).

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry for my late answer.
My biggest issue is that I actually find a "way" (or formula) to find the solution using an example . This makes me usually sucess getting the solution for that example. However my code usually seem to fail other datasets.
I've tried to look for solved examples in internet , but couldn't manage to find a clear explaination. I would be really thankfull if you could picture me your explaination with an example.
Thanks a lot!